# Why is my React useEffect not loading again when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using a useEffect to get information from firebase and set my redux state thereafter. When I open the page for the first time, all my components contain the correct information. As soon as I refresh the page, all the information is set to nothing? I think it is because the useEffect does not execute again for some reason. Here is my code below:

```
    useEffect(async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      await getConfigs().then((response) => {
        const obj = response;
        setRedux(obj[0]);
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you provide an async function as a callback to `useEffect`, which is not allowed. Just get rid of it, like so:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      // Also, you either await or use .then(), not both
      const response = await getConfigs();
      const obj = response;
      setRedux(obj[0]);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: It had no effect at all, but after I removed it nothing changed. In the useEffect I call data from firebase and it gets used on the page. But the problem is when I reload, it does not get information from firebase anymore as the useEffect is not executed again?

Comment: @CodingBoy Are you sure it's not executed? Have you tried debugging or putting a `console.log` statement inside of the callback?

Comment: @CodingBoy I've updated the answer, maybe try that

Comment: So I think I figured out the issue. The problem is in the setRedux function. I will quickly scan the setRedux function and get back to you